# Можно ли изменить ip адрес Ethernet с авто входом в администратора?

Tags: cmd, ip, ос, pyside6, python-3.11

Я хочу у себя производстве операторам роботов сделать такую программу, но в компьютерах есть ограничение прав, если зная админские логин и пароль можно ли сделать не водя пароль и логин изменить ip адрес сети для нужд в других программ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog)
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtGui


import sys
from gui import Ui_Rocoon
from about import Ui_About
import os


# Создать форму и инициализировать пользовательский интерфейс
class ExpenseTracker(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExpenseTracker, self).__init__()
        self.ui_window = Ui_About()
        self.new_window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Rocoon()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Кнопки
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.network)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.network2)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.network3)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.network4)
        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.change)
        self.ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.auto_return)
        self.ui.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.open_window_about)



    # --------------------------------------------------------------
    # Hook logik


    def open_window_about(self):
        self.ui_window.setupUi(self.new_window)
        self.new_window.show()

    def network(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(self.ui.pushButton.text())

    def network2(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(self.ui.pushButton_2.text())

    def network3(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(self.ui.pushButton_3.text())

    def network4(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(self.ui.pushButton_4.text())

    # --------------------------------------------------------------
    # netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
    def change(self):
        ip1 = self.ui.lineEdit_6.text()
        ip2 = self.ui.lineEdit_5.text()
        ip3 = self.ui.lineEdit_7.text()
        ip4 = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text()
        ethernet_ip = f"{ip1}.{ip2}.{ip3}.{ip4}"
        ethernet_name = self.ui.lineEdit.text()

        command = f'netsh interface ip set address name="{ethernet_name}" static {ethernet_ip} 255.255.255.0'
        result1 = os.system(command)  # на выходе получим 0(получилось) или 1(ошибка)

        # Сообщение ошибок
        if result1 == int("0"):
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Rocoon",
                                                               '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" '
                                                               'font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#2ECC71;\">ip '
                                                               'адрес изменился</span></p></body></html>',
                                                               None))

        elif result1 == int("1"):
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Rocoon",
                                                               '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" '
                                                               'font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; '
                                                               'color:#E74C3C;\">Ошибка в вводе '
                                                               'данных</span></p></body></html>',
                                                               None))

    # --------------------------------------------------------------

    # netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" dhcp
    def auto_return(self):
        ethernet_name = self.ui.lineEdit.text()

        command = f'netsh interface ip set address name="{ethernet_name}" dhcp'
        result2 = os.system(command)  # на выходе получим 0(получилось) или 1(ошибка)

        # Сообщение ошибок
        if result2 == int("0"):
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Rocoon",
                                                               '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" '
                                                               'font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#2ECC71;\">ip '
                                                               'адрес получаете автоматически</span></p></body></html>',
                                                               None))

        elif result2 == int("1"):
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Rocoon",
                                                               '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" '
                                                               'font-size:10pt; font-weight:600; '
                                                               'color:#E74C3C;\">Ошибка в вводе '
                                                               'данных</span></p><p align="center"><span style=" '
                                                               'font-size:10pt; font-weight:600; color:#E74C3C;">или '
                                                               'уже получаете ip '
                                                               'автоматически</span></p></body></html>',
                                                               None))

# --------------------------------------------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Racoon.ico'))
    window = ExpenseTracker()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```